# using a custom function for smoothing

Tags: r, ggplot2, interpolation, smoothing

I recently started learning R and ran into a problem using a custom function when plotting.
I want to use the rosin-rammler equation but can't figure out how to use it in my case. In Mathkad, this was easily solved. And here I can not understand.

This is an example of my data and code.

| xy | yy | cat1 | sem1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | №1 |
| 10 | 3 | 0 | №1 |
| 20 | 30 | 0 | №1 |
| 30 | 18 | 0 | №1 |
| 40 | 15 | 0 | №1 |
| 50 | 13 | 0 | №1 |
| 60 | 8 | 0 | №1 |
| 70 | 5 | 0 | №1 |
| 80 | 3 | 0 | №1 |
| 90 | 2 | 0 | №1 |
| 100 | 0 | 0 | №1 |
| 110 | 0 | 0 | №1 |

```
ggplot(allOnw, aes(x = xy, y=yy, col = sem1)) +geom_point()+
  guides(fill = FALSE) +  labs(col="S" )+theme(legend.position="bottom")  +scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 160, by = 10), limits = c(0,160))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "cyan", "darkgreen","darkorange","gold","darkorchid")) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(cat1),ncol = 1, strip.position = "right")+labs(x ="MP")+labs(y = "GT ")
```

I would like the graph to end up looking like when using geom_density.
What can i do for this?
Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with rosin-rammler, but the shallow search I've done so far (e.g., googling for `"cran" "rosin" "rammler"`, quotes important) reveals that the `sievetest` package supports functions for the distribution, but I don't think any of it is in a smoothing role. In fact, I can't find smoothing via that distribution anywhere, including in MathCad. Can you point to any documentation showing how it is being used in any programming language?

Comment: As for *"custom function for smoothing"*, `?geom_smooth` includes `method: Smoothing method (function) to use`, I suggest you look into that.

Comment: From wikipedia it sounds like the "rosin-rammler distribution" is an application of the Weibull distribution. Are you looking to find the best fit Weibull distribution for your data?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346249/fitting-weibull-distribution-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a particular model to fit to your points, you can use `method = nls` inside `geom_smooth`.

As far as I can tell from the [literature](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221664861_A_discrete_model_for_the_apparent_viscosity_of_polydisperse_suspensionsincluding_maximum_packing_fraction/download), the function you are trying to fit takes this form:

```r
rosin_rammler <- function(x, A, B, C) {
  C * ((A / x) * (x / B)^A * exp(-((x / B)^(A - 1))))
}
```

And we can use this directly inside `geom_smooth`:

```r
ggplot(allOnw, aes(x = xy + 1e-6, y = yy, col = sem1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ rosin_rammler(x, A, B, C), method = nls,
              method.args = list(algorithm = "port",
                                 start = list(A = 5, B = 20, C = 1000), 
                                 lower = c(1, 1)), se = FALSE, n = 1000) +
  labs(col = "S", x = "MP", y = "GT")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:16 * 10, limits = c(0, 160)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "cyan", "darkgreen", 
                                      "darkorange", "gold", "darkorchid")) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(cat1), ncol = 1, strip.position = "right")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This will help a lot. This looks very similar to what I wanted. I want to clarify a few points. Why do you add "+1e-6"? Does the row with "method.args" to get the curve with the maximum coefficient of determination? Are these the supposed coefficients in the row, where the coefficients with values ​​​​are indicated (start=list)?

Comment: @GurskiyI I add a tiny value (1e-6) because x = 0 would cause a divide-by-zero error. The coefficients in `start` are just sensible starting points for the parameters. The actual parameters are found by `nls` using a least squares method to get the optimal parameters to fit the data using this model.